# How to run code on a button click in android fragment

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, onclick

I need help trying to make a app work. I set up a multitab interface using fragments(so it there are 4 tabs with diffrent contents) On the fragment i am working on i want to have 3 buttons which run a intent like this:

```
    Log.i(TAG, "Website Clicked");
            Intent websiteBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
            startActivity(websiteBrowserIntent);
```

So i have 3 buttons, heres the .xml:

XML does not seem to work for some reason heres a pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/gGuh7qb2

And here is TopRatedFragment.java:

```
package com.bordengrammar.bordengrammarapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container,         false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds good! But you are probably going to need a `Button` and an `OnClickListener`. Also, what is the question?

Comment: How would i make it so that when i click the button called news, it would take you to a website using the intent in the top. I have tried the normal way, but it seems to be a bit weird as it is a fragment

Comment: get the buttons from the view and set a click listener in the onCreateView

Comment: How would i do such thing? Sorry for this but i am very new and have just got into this fragment thing so and am confused as by what you mean

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container,         false);

        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
    }
}
```

P.S. A little search can get you answers.

**[EDIT]**

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

            Button btn;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container,         false);

                btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {



                    }
                });
                return rootView;
            }
```

Please read some tutorials - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: The type TopRatedFragment must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View), Button cannot be resolved to a type, The method OnClick(View) of type TopRatedFragment must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: @epicfinley ...bit of typo in answer the method is "onClick" not "OnClick".

Comment: @epicfinley Updated the answer along with a edit. Do read some tutorials. Will help you.

Comment: @JoelFernades Still some errors, The method checkStatus() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: @epicfinley Ugh! Man! Just remove it. Updated answer!

Comment: @JoelFernades Just realised this has caused some error in my tabadapter. TabsPagerAdapter.java : http://pastebin.com/T5hgMb6D it is saying Cannot instantiate the type TopRatedFragment